# Set index value in nested map

Tags: javascript, arrays, ramda.js

I have problem when set value in nested map, the assigned value only take the last index value. Is that something I do wrong or I miss?Thank you

Here is my data:

```
const items = [{
  id: 'item1'
}, {
  id: 'item2'
}]

const itemDetails = [{
  name: 'data A',
  class: 'A'
}, {
  name: 'data B',
  class: 'B'
}, {
  name: 'data C',
  class: 'C'
}]
```

The result I expect is:

```
[ 
  [
    { name: 'data A', class: 'A', itemIndex: 0, itemId: 'item1' },
    { name: 'data B', class: 'B', itemIndex: 0, itemId: 'item1' },
    { name: 'data C', class: 'C', itemIndex: 0, itemId: 'item1' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'data A', class: 'A', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' },
    { name: 'data B', class: 'B', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' },
    { name: 'data C', class: 'C', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' }
  ]
]
```

But I got this result using nested map:

```
[
  [
    { name: 'data A', class: 'A', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' },
    { name: 'data B', class: 'B', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' },
    { name: 'data C', class: 'C', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' }
  ],
  [
    { name: 'data A', class: 'A', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' },
    { name: 'data B', class: 'B', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' },
    { name: 'data C', class: 'C', itemIndex: 1, itemId: 'item2' }
  ]
]
```

My Code:

```
const result = items.map((item, itemIdx) => {
  return itemDetails.map(detail => {
    detail.itemIndex = itemIdx
    detail.itemId = item.id

    return detail
  })
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged "ramda.js".  There's no Ramda in the question, nor any request to use it.  But I also don't think Ramda would do anything to improve on the excellent answer from Rox.

Comment: Sorry I am using "ramda.js" tag, because I also using some Ramda in my other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please first create a copy of the original detail and then mutate it.

This should work fine:

```
const result = items.map((item, itemIdx) => {
  return itemDetails.map(detail => {
    const newDetail = {...detail}
    newDetail.itemIndex = itemIdx
    newDetail.itemId = item.id

    return newDetail;
  })
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Less code:

```
const result = items.map((item, itemIndex) => 
  itemDetails.map(detail => ({...detail, itemIndex, itemId: item.id})))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var resArr=[];
// I am using .length in loops if your data is large you can precalculate the values  // intovariables and use them
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    const id = items[i]["id"];
    var temparr=[]
    for(var j=0;j<itemDetails.length;j++){
        let obj={"name":itemDetails[j]["name"],"class":itemDetails[j]["class"],"itemIndex":i,"itemId":id}
        temparr.push(obj);}
    resArr.push(temparr)
}
```

console.log(resArr);